# Not receiving updates when InlineKeyboard button is pressed

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api

I made a Telegram Bot using pure PHP (a class of mine) for adding Inline Keyboard to channel posts. When you press the button it changes the counter on it.

Webhook is set. I receive the `channel_post` update, call `editMessageReplyMarkup` and inline button is being added to the post. When I press this button, I receive `callback_query` update, handle it with `editMessageReplyMarkup` (changing the counter) and answer using `answerCallbackQuery`. Simple as it is.

Works fine on my test channel and the new ones I created. But when it comes to my second channel (about 6 months old), I receive only `channel_post` update. When I press the button nothing happens. On the client side it looks handled as if `answerCallbackQuery` with no text was sent, but no `callback_query` update received on the server side.

Any thoughts?